# XAML child window subclass: "InitializeComponent shadows member in base class." How can I resolve this warning without modifying autogenerated code?

Tags: vb.net, xaml, compiler-warnings, auto-generate, initializecomponent

I have added two windows to a Silverlight 5 application project: `FooWindowBase` and `SomeFooWindow`. The latter is a sub-class of the former. Both contain a default constructor calling `InitializeComponent`, and apparently Visual Studio or the compiler autogenerates that method. This leads to the following compiler warning in the derived class `SomeFooWindow` that…

> *"sub `InitializeComponent` shadows an overloadable member declared in the base class `FooWindowBase`. If you want to overload the base method, this method must be declared `Overloads`."*

Since `InitializeComponent` was autogenerated in both cases, there seems to be no way for me to add a `Shadows` over `Overloads` specifier.

Is there any way to prevent, or get rid of, this compiler warning without editing the autogenerated code?

---

**`FooWindowBase`:**

- XAML:

  ```
  <c:ChildWindow 
      x:Class="FooNamespace.FooWindowBase"
      xmlns:c="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
      …>
    …
  </c:ChildWindow>
  ```
- Code:

  ```vb
  Imports System.Windows.Controls

  Partial MustInherit Class FooWindowBase : Inherits ChildWindow
      Public Sub New()
          InitializeComponent()
      End Sub
      …
  End Class
  ```

---

**`SomeFooWindow:`**

- XAML:

  ```
  <l:FooWindowBase
      x:Class="FooNamespace.SomeFooWindow"
      xmlns:l="clr-namespace:FooNamespace;assembly=Foo"
      …>
    …
  </l:FooWindowBase>
  ```
- Code:

  ```vb
  Partial Class SomeFooWindow : Inherits FooWindowBase
      Public Sub New()
          InitializeComponent()
      End Sub
      …
  End Class
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post the workaround I have ended up using for others who are facing the same problem.

One posted answer to [this question asked on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/111977/) mentions that:

> *"Currently deriving a XAML generated class from another XAML generated class is not supported."*

and the solution would be to:

> *"[…] define your base class all in code without using XAML."*

The exact same words are mentioned on [this Microsoft Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/957231), btw. So basically, the compiler warning cannot be gotten rid of because that inheritance scenario I've posted simply isn't supported.

I ended up doing the following:

1. turned the derived class `SomeFooWindow` into a `UserControl` called `SomeFooControl`;
2. renamed `FooWindowBase` to `FooWindow` and removed the `MustInherit` modifier;
3. added a named `ContentPresenter` control to `FooWindow`;
4. instead of instantiating the previous `SomeFooWindow`, instantiated a `FooWindow` and set the `ContentPresenter`'s content to an instance of a `SomeFooControl`:

   ```
   Dim someFooWindow = New FooWindow(…)
   someFooWindow.Content = New SomeFooControl(…)
   ```